# How to filter s3 objects by last modified date with Boto3

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

Is there a way to filter s3 objects by last modified date in boto3? I've constructed a large text file list of all the contents in a bucket. Some time has passed and I'd like to list only objects that were added after the last time I looped through the entire bucket.

I know I can use the `Marker` property to start from a certain object name,so I could give it the last object I processed in the text file but that does not guarantee a new object wasn't added before that object name. e.g. if the last file in the text file was oak.txt and a new file called apple.txt was added, it would not pick that up.

```
s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
client = boto3.client('s3')

def list_rasters(bucket):

    bucket = s3_resource.Bucket(bucket)

    for bucket_obj in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix="testing_folder/"):
        print bucket_obj.key
        print bucket_obj.last_modified
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The following code snippet gets all objects under specific folder and check if the file last modified is created after the time you specify :

Replace `YEAR,MONTH, DAY` with your values.

```
import boto3
import datetime
#bucket Name
bucket_name = 'BUCKET NAME'
#folder Name
folder_name = 'FOLDER NAME'
#bucket Resource
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket(bucket_name)    
def lambda_handler(event, context):
     for file in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix= folder_name):
         #compare dates 
         if file.last_modified.replace(tzinfo = None) > datetime.datetime(YEAR,MONTH, DAY,tzinfo = None):
             #print results
             print('File Name: %s ---- Date: %s' % (file.key,file.last_modified))
```

Comment: Why did you define `lambda_handler()`? Why call it that? And what is `event` and `context`? How is that relevant to OP's question? It confused the schnitzel out of me when I read it. Also, OP specifically said he doesn't want to loop through the whole thing, and yet you loop through the whole folder.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a more optimized solution to get object keys filtered by `LastModified` field.

```
s3 = boto3.client("s3")
s3_paginator = s3.get_paginator('list_objects_v2')
s3_iterator = s3_paginator.paginate(Bucket="SampleBucket")
filtered_iterator = s3_iterator.search(
    "Contents[?to_string(LastModified)>='\"2023-03-01 00:00:00+00:00\"'].Key"
)

for key_data in filtered_iterator:
    print(key_data)
```

You can modify the iterator search string to get the necessary fields.

Answer (score 5):

The code snippet below will use the s3 Object class get() action to only return those that meet a IfModifiedSince datetime argument. The script prints the files, which was the original questions, but also saves the files locally.

```
import boto3
import io
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta


# Defining AWS S3 resources
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('<bucket_name>')
prefix = '<object_key_prefix, if any>'

# note this based on UTC time
yesterday = datetime.fromisoformat(str(date.today() - timedelta(days=1)))

# function to retrieve Streaming Body from S3 with timedelta argument
def get_object(file_name):
    try:
        obj = file_name.get(IfModifiedSince=yesterday)
        return obj['Body']
    except:
        False


# obtain a list of s3 Objects with prefix filter
files = list(bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=prefix))

# Iterating through the list of files
# Loading streaming body into a file with the same name
# Printing file name and saving file
# Note skipping first file since it's only the directory

for file in files[1:]:
    file_name = file.key.split(prefix)[1] # getting the file name of the S3 object
    s3_file = get_object(file) # streaming body needing to iterate through
    if s3_file: # meets the modified by date
        print(file_name) # prints files not modified since timedelta
        try:
            with io.FileIO(file_name, 'w') as f:
                for i in s3_file: # iterating though streaming body
                    f.write(i)
        except TypeError as e:
            print(e, file)
```