# How to list objects in a date range with aws-sdk-js?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-js

I'm looking to list all the objects stored in S3 bucket between two dates using aws s3 javascript sdk.According to [ListObjects](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#listObjects) function there is no parameter allowing to do that except a `prefix`or `delimiter` but in my case they are useless.
Is there any solution to do that or I have to get the returned data then filter them according to `LastModified`?

Comment: I have a working piece in boto3 if that's helpful..

Comment: @AmitBaranes can you give me the link ?

Comment: Sure - https://stackoverflow.com/a/59146547/9931092 You need to add another compare condition under the if statement, Let me know if you need help with that

Comment: @AmitBaranes it is the solution that I thought about it, but if the bucket contains a lot of objects(1M for e.g) we have to get all of them then filter by date manually.I think there is not option to do that using the aws s3 api directly according to what I found in the official documentation.

Comment: To be honest I've never used aws s3 api for doing this kind of thing since boto3 is pretty much straight forward and very easy to use. The example I provided fits your requirements? By the way, when using `bucket.objects.filter(Prefix= folder_name)` you get the metadata of the object, which means it doesn't matter if the object size is 1MB or 1GB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation and the answer I got according to the [issue 3102](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/3102), there is no existing api at the moment of writing this answer, so I do it manually:

```
async function filteredKeysByDate(startDate, endDate) {
const listedObjects = await s3.listObjects({
Bucket: 'myBucket'
Prefix: 'prefix'})

 return listedObjects.reduce((acc, file) => {
  if (file.LastModified >= startDate && file.LastModified <= endDate) {
    acc= acc.concat(file)
  }
   return acc;
  }, [])
}
```