# Delete files under S3 bucket recursively without deleting folders using python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I'm getting error, When i try to delete all files under specific folder
Problem is here ['Key': 'testpart1/*.*']
Also i would like to delete 30 days older file, please help me with script

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
my_bucket = s3.Bucket('my-bucket')

response = my_bucket.delete_objects(
    Delete={
        'Objects': [
            {
                'Key': 'testpart1/*.*'   # the_name of_your_file
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: The `delete_objects()` command requires a list of objects to delete. It does _not_ accept wildcards (eg `/*`). You would first need to obtain a list of objects, and then pass those Keys (filenames) to the `delete_objects()` command. If you wish to delete objects older than 30 days, you would use the `LastModified` date from the list of objects to determine whether or not to delete the objects.

Comment: FYI, Amazon S3 [Object lifecycle management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-lifecycle-mgmt.html) can automatically delete objects in S3 older than a given number of days. This is useful if you regularly want to purge a bucket (or folder) of old files.

Answer (score 2):

The code below will delete all files under the prefix recursively:

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
my_bucket = s3.Bucket('my-bucket')

response = my_bucket.objects.filter(Prefix="testpart1/").delete()
```

Please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/59146547/4214976 to filter out the object based on date.

Comment: if i want to delete all files under my-bucket ? Prefix="*/"

Comment: then `my_bucket.objects.all().delete()` will work, thiswilldelete all files under the bucket.

Comment: if the bucket is versioned you canuse `my_bucket.object_versions.delete()`

Comment: With "my_bucket.objects.all().delete()" not only files, folders also getting deleted, can we filter only files

Comment: I think there's no such thing as "only folders" in bucket. If there's on file inside, there's no folder either. Right?

Comment: If the "New folder" button is used in the S3 console, it will create a zero-length object with the name of the folder. This 'forces' the folder to appear even when no objects exist. So, it is a 'simulated folder'. In general, however, folders do not actually exist in Amazon S3.

Comment: With PowerShell script i can delete only files under my-bucket, folders can be excluded while deleting, similarly i'm looking on python


<< aws s3 rm s3://my-bucket/ --recursive --exclude="*" --include="*/*.*" >>

Comment: Folders do not actually exist in Amazon S3. You can put a file where ever you want, and the folders will magically "appear". Then, when the files are deleted, the folder will "disappear". _Why_ do you wish to retain folders in S3?