# List Amazon S3 bucket contents from yesterday. List contents with todays date with 1 or more days subtracted?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

```
aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket BUCKET_NAME  --query 'Contents[?LastModified>=`YYYY-MM-DD`].Key'
```

In the above you have to manually put in the date, but I want it just to get the todays date and subtract 1 day or more depends on the demand.

How do the syntax look if you want files from 1 day back ?

is it possible to get todays date and use it with `some[-1]` with either the `aws s3api` or `aws s3 ls`?

Comment: This isn't possible with the use of only the AWS CLI as neither it nor the JMESPath grammar supports math with date values.

Comment: You can do it programmatically if you're good at Shell Script, or you could do it via Python: [How to filter s3 objects by last modified date with Boto3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59143045/174777). Also note that dates are stored in UTC, so your definition of "yesterday" might differ.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't just do this within that single aws cli command.

You have to build the date variable prior to running the aws cli command.

```
DATE=$(date +'20%y-%m-%d')
aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket BUCKET_NAME  --query 'Contents[?LastModified>=`$DATE`].Key'
```

Comment: Thanks, Fixed it.
it needs to be formatted to the s3api timeformat. This example is to get files 3 days back.  

`code` $DATE="{0:s}{0:zzz}" -f (Get-date).adddays(-3) 

`code` aws s3api list-objects --bucket <BUCKET_NAME> --output text  --prefix <prefix> --query "Contents[?LastModified>= '$DATE'].{Key: Key, LastModified: LastModified }"